# How are gestures implemented in Surface SDK?

Tags: gesture, pixelsense, multi-touch

I wonder how gestures like move, scale, rotate are implemented in Surface SDK. Do you need to listen to specific events? Do they provide scale/rotate center point? Do they feel natural? (where natural is when you move one finger but don't move another one the CENTER point is at the second one) How gestures cope with multiple fingers, not just tho distinct touches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 components:

1) A ManipulationProcessor API.  This takes a series of touch input events and tells you in aggregate how much rotation/scaling/translation has been done.  There are lots of configuration parameters on this and different versions for C++, XNA/WinForms, Silverlight, and WPF - each tailored towards the target development platform

2) More frequently, developers will simply work with one of the many WPF controls that the SDK comes with.  These include ScatterView which fascilitates the user moving/rotating/resizing several objects around the screen and also simpler controls like SurfaceListBox and SurfaceScrollViewer which fascilitate simple translation gestures over a list or other arbitrary UI element.